# Complex javascript function, how can I use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, readiumjs

I found the following pattern but i'm not sure how to call this one.

```
test(var1, {
    subTest1: test1Function(function(var2) {
        // elided
    }),
    subTest2: test2Function(html) {
        // elided
    }
});
```

I need to call `subTest1`, how can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Refferance:[Javascript page link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/readium/readium-js-viewer/master/lib/Readium.js)(Line-10975)

Answer (score 1):

From [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) i have found out that the `extend` is a high level function that copies the prototype of a new subclass that you want to extend from the base class,to call subTest1 you will do it like a normal method obj1.subTest1(var2)

The corect sintax is

```
extend(obj1, {
   subTest1: test1Function(function(var2) {
    .
    .
   }),
  subTest2: test2Function(html) {
    .
    .
   })
});
```